# What does "true-crime bragging" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I've come across it in the 9th episode of the 3rd season of *Rick and Morty*. Here is the context:

> Beth: Wow. He's really getting executed after all this time. You know the son that he ate was--
>
> Summer: Your best friend-- Tommy. We know. Stop **true-crime bragging**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Stop proudly telling stories (= bragging) about that true crime (= the crime that actually happened, and involved real people).

Summer interrupted Beth because they already know the story or/and the topic is unpleasant/disturbing to talk about.

Also, [true crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_crime) is a genre in literature and cinema to examine actual (particularly strange, shocking, or sensational) crimes.

Answer (score 2):

*True-crime-bragging* is a new coinage, a one-off phrase.  It's meant to evoke the recently popularized *humblebrag*

---

#### Humblebrag

> **humblebrag** verb
>
> : to make a seemingly modest, self-critical, or casual statement or reference that is meant to draw attention to one's admirable or impressive qualities or achievements

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humblebrag

This definition is not especially clear, and people use the phrase pretty inconsistently.

To my mind, a humblebrag is a statement *sounds* like it's meant to evoke sympathy, but which is *actually* meant to provoke jealously, or to show off.

Here's a little illustration: imagine a person has just paid someone to build them a large and unusual house.

If the person wanted to ***brag***, they would say: "This house was so large and unusual that only someone as rich as me could afford to pay for it."

To ***humblebrag***, the person would imply the same thing (only I'm rich enough), but would phrase the statement differently, so that the listener might think we're supposed to feel bad for them: "It's *so difficult* to build a house like this.  Getting all the permits was a nightmare.  I wish I had built something smaller and simpler."

---

#### True-crime-brag

This one-off phrase should be understood as a specific form of humblebragging - one that relates to the ["true crime"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_crime) genre.

In the example text, Beth makes a statement which seems like it's meant to evoke sympathy: "I'm sad/scared/upset because the person he killed was my best friend."

But the statement also, or actually, invites envy: "We're all interested in this exciting murder case - I deserve special attention because I knew the person who was killed."